# how can add a herf link to form button in blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, blogger

I'm new to  here ....  i need some codes for in my blog ..
I use below code in my blog post .....

```
<form>
    <input type=button value="click to  Download" onclick="window.open('google.com')" >
</form>
```

but i need this 
    " if  click on that button  a particular  url  must be  open in next window ...".

Another  problem is another form button for watching video

```
<form>`
    <input type=button value="click to  watch video" onClick= <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/d49PBvzEyjE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> >
</form>
```

if click on this button , embedded video will  be appear and  play below on that  button...
Thanks you sir

Comment: What you have tried???

Comment: If you want to open a link a new window you need to use a "a" tag

Comment: are you trying to use a button instead of link?

Answer (score 0):

Using `target="_blank"` will instruct the browser to create a new browser tab or window when the user clicks on the link

```
<a href="yoururl" target="_blank">Click to open in new window</a>
```

And use **Iframe** to load video below button to open video

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form>
    <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Click to  Download</a>
</form>
```

`target="_blank"` - Opens the linked document in a new window or tab. More on target attribute [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)